# Firebase Web app signInWithEmailAndPassword problem

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with FireBase Web app signInWithEmailAndPassword.
When I press the button `Sign In` it's showing an only progress bar.
I after that I try to get data from the database and it is working but this `signInWithEmailAndPassword` isn't working 
 and here is my code 
And If else isn't working becouse when i press the button with "" empty field result is true, not false

I after that i try to get data from the database and it is working but this signInWithEmailAndPassword isnt working

And this is my function for sign in

```
$("#loginbtn").click(
  function(){
    var email = $("loginemail").val();
    var password = $("loginpassword").val();

    if(email != "" && password != ""){
        $("#loginprogress").show();
        $("#loginbtn").hide();

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {            
          $("#loginerror").show();

          $("#loginprogress").hide();
          $("#loginbtn").show();           
          });
    }else{
        windows.alert("Error");
    }
  }
```

);

Comment: What isn't working when you call `signInWithEmailAndPassword(...)`? Is there an error message? Or does the code you shared to something that you don't expect it to do?

Comment: This code isnt working for me . It should work like ... if enter exsiting account  output would be true but if field is empty  should go false .. but for me all case go to  flalse

Comment: The code doesn't have any `true` or `false` output, so I don't really understand what you mean. As far as I can see, your code will remain silent when the user signs in. If you want to respond to that, have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user